# Why is MS word saving the document in txt form and not a DOCX

Tags: windows, ms-word, doc, notepad

Example
I created a word document Named "DOC"  this is a word document that is being saved in TXT format and not
DOCX format.
This has been happening to all the Word documents on my system.
I open a word doc made changes then saved as (different name) and it still saved it in a TXT format.

Comment: When you "Save as", do you see an option to select the filetype? What option is selected there by default?

Comment: Yes I select the option Word document (*,docx)

Comment: Can you add the screenshot of it, how it looks in file explorer and the properties box?

Comment: I can not past a screen shot, but here is what it looks like

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps below:

1. Click the File tab
2. Click Options
3. Click Save

Under Save documents, click Word Document (*.docx) in the Save files in this format.

Comment: I have looked options SAVE in the save file is in this format - Word document (*,DOCX)

Comment: When is interesting it shows the filetype  is in  DOCX File

Answer (score 0):

Open the Properties of the file and check whether it is saved with the extension `.doc` or `.docx`, and if it doesn't, then make sure you choose he correct extension in `Save As` dialog box!

Another Case is that, your default application for opening the `.doc` or `.docx` would be set to Notepad. So, kindly check that too

Comment: I can not paste  a screen shot, but here is what it looks like   DOC1 7/28/2020 11:31am DOCX File 2,151KB.  When I open  it comes up as a NOTEPAD doc in TXT format. It shows it is a DOCX not as a TXT

Comment: I have checked the option SAVE it is save as a DOCX. Where do I go to set the default application, This may be the answer to the issue.

Comment: Right Click on your File, Hover on `Open With` and Choose `Ms-Word`.

Comment: That is how I open it in a Word format, But why is it being saved in a TXT format?

Comment: I think it is not saving in TXT format. You have to set the default application to open.
Right Click on your File, Hover on `Open With` and click on `Choose Default Program` or `Choose another app` and Choose Ms-Word and mark a tick on `Default App` and then click `Ok`

Comment: I got the answer, From the control panel go to SET DEFAULT by APP. GO to WORD open in 'manage' . for to Word DOCX There a window comes up and there choose WORD. This solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help.